# Laplace transform problem

Tags: signal, laplace-transform

Can you help me with these laplace problems ? I'm having trouble understanding how to do it. ( u(t) is heaviside step function )

[image]

Comment: \$u(t)\$ might refer to the [unit step function](https://www.intmath.com/laplace-transformation/1a-unit-step-functions-definition.php)

Comment: Can you show what you have tried already? Homework questions are OK to ask, but you have to show what you've tried and where you are getting stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the definition of Laplace (see the limits of integration) and write down the formulas.

Think that Laplace is property additive ? You can therefore write Laplace formulas for each term for the first one : a) and c).
For the b), think a little about after writing down the formula cos with complex exponentials.

When done, poles and zeros appears clearly.
What is ROC ?  (google it with Laplace) https://www.tutorialspoint.com/signals_and_systems/region_of_convergence.htm

If I made no errors ... Here are my answers to help ... my old "Maple" sheet. Something strange. Perhaps a bug. Are you sure that in the first line, it is ...*u(-t) ? Ok. Verification done. see link above.
Theory is not always related to "physical phenomena".

[image]